# Convert integer data into year and month

Tags: r, date

I have integer data example like this

```
201901, 201912, 202004
```

How to convert my data into year and month using R Programming. I need output like this:

```
2019-01, 2019-12, 2020-04
```

or

```
Jan-2019, Dec-2019, Apr-2020
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert to date and then use `format` :

```
x <- c(201901, 201912, 202004)

format(as.Date(paste(x, '01'), '%Y%m%d'), '%b-%Y')
#[1] "Jan-2019" "Dec-2019" "Apr-2020"
format(as.Date(paste(x, '01'), '%Y%m%d'), '%Y-%m')
#[1] "2019-01" "2019-12" "2020-04"
```

---

You can also use `zoo`'s `yearmon` :

```
zoo::as.yearmon(as.character(x), '%Y%m')
```

---

Using regex we can capture 4 and 2 characters and insert a "-" in between.

```
sub('(.{4})(.{2})', '\\1-\\2', x)
```